# Error in XML file making R not work

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have an error in this XML  file which is causing eclipse to not recognize R. What could be causing this?

```
<menu 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    myapp:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/action_quotes" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_emoticons" 
    android:title="Quotes"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/action_pics" 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" 
    android:title="Pictures"
    myapp:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: try to clean and built u r project.

Comment: I tried cleaning the project but it doesnt help.

Comment: remove this and try `xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Remove : `xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Removing alone won't do the job, you'll also have to replace myapp with android.

Comment: it still wont recognize R. :(

Comment: can you post error from log-cat..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myapp:showAsAction` is not a valid prefix. It should be `android:showAsAction`

Change to the following:

```
<menu 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item
 android:id="@+id/action_settings"
 android:orderInCategory="100"
 android:showAsAction="never"
 android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_quotes" 
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_emoticons" 
 android:title="Quotes"
 android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_pics" 
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" 
 android:title="Pictures"
 android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: this stops my items from working. how can I fix that?

Comment: @user3246935 it stops your item from working?... I have tested it, and its fine. what do you mean, not working. The errors should have gone.

Comment: I have an action bar with two items. In my java code these items stop working when I click the items.

Comment: The Syntax is: `android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]` The fact they dont work when you press them is another question. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: @user3246935 Good to hear. Consider upvoting and marking this answer as correct :) Thanks